# JPQL, get all ManyToMany relations defined in a JoinTable by primary key

Tags: sql, jpql

I have two entities `Project` and `Employee`. They have a Many to Many relation in a Jointable. Given an unique primary id of an employee, how would I find all its related projects?

I tried something like this, but that gives me a `RunTimeException` which states that it couldnt extract the `ResultSet`.

```
  @Query("SELECT new packagename.Project(project.id, moreFields..." +
          "FROM Project project, Employee employee" +
          "WHERE employee.id = :id AND project IN (employee.projects))
  List<Project> findByEmployeesEmailInOneRequest(@Param("id") long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
select p from Employee e join e.projects p where e.id = :id`
```

Or, without any query

```
Set<Project> projects = em.find(Employee.class, id).getProjects();
```